# Expand 2f[x] to f[x]+f[x] (Simplify sums of ArcTan)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I'm trying to simplify an expression with sums of `ArcTan`, for which I've written a transformation rule that works for simple sums, so that `ArcTan[a] + ArcTan[b] -> ArcTan[(a+b)/(1-ab)]`. However, it fails for terms of the type `5 ArcTan[a] + ArcTan[b]`. One way to simplify this expression would be to expand the integer into a sum of units, then transform repeatedly until the expression consists of only one `ArcTan`, but I haven't been able so far to find the way.

I've tried `Hold`,`Distribute`, `Sum`,`Fold` with `Plus`to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
ArcTan[Simplify[TrigExpand[Tan[5 ArcTan[a] + ArcTan[b]]]]]
```

[image: ArcTan Simplify]

Could save yourself some work!

## Explanation:

The trick here is to understand the identity you mentioned is about Tan, not ArcTan:

Tan[x+y] = (Tan[x]+Tan[y])/(1 -Tan[x]Tan[y]).

TrigExpand does the above type of expansion for trig functions. Replace x and y with ArcTan[a] and ArcTan[b], then take ArcTan of both sides and you have your identity.
Simplify collects the terms of the expansion into one.

The same method works for any linear combination of x=Arctan[a] and y=Arctan[b].

Comment: Thanks. Simple and effective. Is there some reference for simplifications in Mathematica?

Comment: I just checked the help file for ArcTan. Look at ref/ArcTan->Applications->Addition theorem for tangent function. They use exactly the same technique, which is reassuring. There are various tutorials in the document centre. Look under "Algebraic Manipulation". However I simply search for a function e.g. TrigExpand and then use "See Also" at the bottom to find other related functions e.g. TrigReduce.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
5 ArcTan[a] + ArcTan[b] /.
 {(m_Integer: 1) ArcTan[a_] + (n_Integer: 1) ArcTan[b_] /; Positive[m] && Positive[n] :>
   With[{min = Min[m, n]},
    (m - min) ArcTan[a] + (n - min) ArcTan[b] + 
     min ArcTan[(a + b)/(1 - ab)]]}

(* 4 ArcTan[a] + ArcTan[(a + b)/(1 - ab)] *)
```

Works on positive integral coefficients, which is how I read the question:

```
7 ArcTan[a] + 4 ArcTan[b] /.
 {(m_Integer: 1) ArcTan[a_] + (n_Integer: 1) ArcTan[b_] /; Positive[m] && Positive[n] :>
   With[{min = Min[m, n]},
    (m - min) ArcTan[a] + (n - min) ArcTan[b] + 
     min ArcTan[(a + b)/(1 - ab)]]}

(* 3 ArcTan[a] + 4 ArcTan[(a + b)/(1 - ab)] *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to change `a` to `a_` and `b` to `b_` for this to work with arbitrary arguments. Is there a way to do the expansion in the title?

Comment: Also, generalization to negative integers requires to write 2 more transformation rules or is there a simpler way? Mathematica automatically simplifies `ArcTan[-x]` to `-ArcTan[x]` and makes it harder, is there a way to stop automatic simplifications?

Comment: In order to incorporate negative integers, this seems to work: `ArcTanSimplify = {(m_Integer: 1) ArcTan[a_] + (n_Integer: 1) ArcTan[
       b_] :> With[{min = Min[Abs[{m, n}]]}, 
     Sign[m] (Abs[m] - min) ArcTan[a] + 
      Sign[n] (Abs[n] - min) ArcTan[b] + 
      min ArcTan[(Sign[m] a + Sign[n] b)/(1 - Sign[m n] a b)]]};`

Comment: @auxsvr Yes, using `Abs` was my first thought.  Fixed the `a` to `a_` -- I had thought about it before, but it was late.  Can't think why I went for the literal `a` in the first place.

Comment: @auxsvr You can clean up a bit via MinimalBy (v10):
`m_. ArcTan[a_] + n_. ArcTan[b_] :> 
 With[{min = 
    First@MinimalBy[{m, n}, Abs]}, (m - min) ArcTan[
     a] + (n - min) ArcTan[b] + min ArcTan[(a + b)/(1 - a b)]]`